# What happen to value assigned to first variable in python?

Tags: python

I am learning python where i come across below scenario

Can someone brief what actually happening with first variable value `a=10`

Where it is going or does it getting garbage collected by python ?

```
a=10
a=15
print (a)
```

**My output comes as :** `15`

Comment: It is going nowhere. Maybe it has been garbage collected, but maybe not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object reference of `a` remains and gets re-assigned on the second line; nothing is garbage collected

Comment: The 10 may have been garbage collected (in theory).

Comment: @mkrieger1No, `int`s atleast upto 255(?) are interned. There's no garbage collection happening.

Comment: Yes, *in practice* it's not. But a Python interpreter could be written that does it and it would be allowed.

Comment: @OneCricketeer  can you elaborate a little more

Comment: @codeholic I don't know what else there is to elaborate on. Visualize the code here http://pythontutor.com/